# Why does PostgreSQL not match several spaces with regular expression "\s+"

Tags: regex, postgresql

**UPDATE**: Comments suggested that there might be some invisible spaces chars and in the data.  This seemed to be the source of the problem.

---

I have the following table:

```
SELECT id, name FROM phototagging_category;
 id |      name       
----+-----------------
  1 | new
  2 | hhh
  3 | Más      Habana
  4 | Más Habana
(4 rows)
```

When I issue the following query I expect the last two rows to match the regular expression, but only the last is returned:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM phototagging_category WHERE UNACCENT(name) ~* 'mas\s+habana';
 id |    name    
----+------------
  4 | Más Habana
(1 row)
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 12 (the docker image postgis/postgis:12-3.0-alpine).

Any ideas about why the 3rd row is not a match?

Comment: This should work.  Perhaps there is an extra space after Habana in the 3rd record or some other invisible character?

Comment: There is probably a character in there which is not visible, but also not considered a white space.  What do you get if you set bytea_output to escape, then `select name::bytea FROM phototagging_category where id=3`?

Comment: Without having your data, it is hard to suggest any precise solution, but I am sure `where UNACCENT(s) ~* 'mas\W+habana'` will work. Most probably there are some invisible non-whitespace chars in between `Más` and `Habana`

Comment: I didn't check that. Apparently there was such chars.  After, `update phototagging_category set name='Mas     Habana' where id=3;` the query returned the 3rd row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments there seemed to be some invisible chars in the 3rd row.

After updating with:

```sql
UPDATE phototagging_category SET name='Mas     Habana' WHERE id=3;
```

The row now shows in the result of the query.